# How to JOIN after GROUP BY using GROUP_CONCAT?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have two tables as

```
CREATE TABLE texts
(
TextID int(11) unsigned,
SentenceID int(11) unsigned,
Phrase tinyint(3) unsigned,
Word varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY(TextID,SentenceID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE phrases
(
PhraseID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Phrase varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY(PhraseID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

I get the phrases from text table by `GROUP BY`,

```
SELECT TRIM(GROUP_CONCAT(Word SEPARATOR ' '))  AS GroupedPhrase
FROM texts 
WHERE Phrase IS NOT NULL GROUP BY TextID,SentenceID,Phrase
```

but I need to `JOIN` two tables to get `PhraseID` instead of `Phrase`, a query to do this:

```
SELECT a.TextID,a.SentenceID,b.PhraseID 
FROM texts a JOIN phrases b ON TRIM(GROUP_CONCAT(a.Word SEPARATOR ' '))=b.Phrase 
WHERE a.Phrase IS NOT NULL GROUP BY a.TextID,a.SentenceID,a.Phrase
```

Comment: Maybe your schema needs revision. What is `Phrase tinyint(3) unsigned` for ? Joining on large varchar strings wont be efficient.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I should modify the naming, `Phrase tinyint(3) unsigned` is the `phrase number` in each `SentenceID`.

Comment: I don't understand the data structure.  You have defined `textid`/`sentenceid` as the primary key.  There is no need to add `phrase` to a `group by` for instance.  In fact, there is no need to aggregate by both columns at all.

Comment: Unless, there is a mismatch in phrases between the two tables; I feel that you should only store phrase_id in the text table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT TextID,SentenceID,TRIM(GROUP_CONCAT(Word SEPARATOR ' '))  AS GroupedPhrase
     FROM texts 
     WHERE Phrase IS NOT NULL 
     GROUP BY TextID,SentenceID,Phrase) sub
JOIN phrases b ON sub.GroupedPhrase=b.Phrase
```

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP_CONCAT()` does not guarantee the ordering of the values unless you use an `ORDER BY`.  If you are matching the words, then you should use an `ORDER BY`.

Unfortunately, your sentence doesn't have an obvious column to use for ordering.  In fact, your data model is quite curious.

I might guess that your intend for `Phrase` to be used for this purpose:

```
SELECT tsp.*, p.PhraseId
FROM (SELECT TextID, SentenceID,
             GROUP_CONCAT(Word ORDER BY phrase SEPARATOR ' '))  AS GroupedPhrase
      FROM texts 
      WHERE Phrase IS NOT NULL 
      GROUP BY TextID, SentenceID
     ) tsp JOIN
     phrases p
     ON tsp.GroupedPhrase = p.Phrase;
```

If you do not have such a column, you should add it in.

Comment: you're right, `Phrase`, which should be named `phrase_number` is the column for `ORDER BY`. Thanks for the hint.